# Where query on Eloquent All()

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

```
$table = ExampleTable::all();
$elem = $table->find(1);
```

While above works, receding does not:

```
$table = ExampleTable::all();
$elem = $table->where('id', 1)->first();
```

Is there a way to achieve latter other than `DB::table`?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Getting the entry with id `1`? Why do you get all entries and then filter them? You can just use `ExampleTable::find(1);`.

Comment: Yes, I know that @JonasStaudenmeir. In this particular case, I need to get all data first and then I have to be able to run queries like 'where' on it. And I have not to use DB::table while doing this.

Comment: What exact Laravel version do you use?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, 4.2.

Comment: Why are trying to use `$table->where()` instead of `table->find()`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir because I have to chain multiple where clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where()` isn't available in Laravel 4.2, you have to use `filter()`:

```
$table->filter(function($value) {
    return $value->id == 1;
});
```